# PHP fastest method for searching files recursively

Tags: php

Hello developer friends,

i have a task that described as my question subject. in my case, the directory structure is deep enough and this is the directory sample:

```
D:\DATA\PROGRAM 11\AREA 01\CAB 001\JS 0100 INSIGHT\2008\01 JANUARY\01
```

i have to find image files inside each last child directory. I have to find files with the help from some parameters, some parameter are string that contain in file_name, and some parameter to help system match directory name then searching method can be more accurately. My code still not complete and take long time to complete, it's about 4-5 minutes.
please see my code below,

```
<?php
function readdirScandir($dir, $extension)
{ 
$files = array();
$root = @scandir($dir, SCANDIR_SORT_NONE);
foreach($root as $entry)
{
    if($entry === '.' || $entry === '..') 
        continue;

    $fullpath = $dir.'/'.$entry;
    if(is_file($fullpath)) 
    {
        if (0 === strcasecmp($extension, pathinfo($fullpath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)))
            $files[] = $fullpath;
        continue;
    }

    foreach(readdirScandir($fullpath, $extension) as $entry)
    {
        if(0 === strcasecmp($extension, pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)))
        {
            $files[] = $entry;
        }
    }
}
return $files;
}


$root_dir = getcwd();

//place this before any script you want to calculate time
$time_start = microtime(true);

// include subdirectories
$dirlist = readdirScandir($root_dir, 'tif');

var_dump($dirlist);

$time_end = microtime(true);

//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes other wise seconds
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

//execution time of the script
echo '<br><b>Total Execution Time:</b> '.$execution_time.' Mins';
?>
```

I would appreciate every advice and your help. Thanks in advance and nice weekend.

Comment: Take a profiler and profile your code.

Comment: why you give me minus? i really wanna know the best method first, about time i tcould be estimated later

Comment: I have not downvoted you. If you want to optimise your code - first profile it. There is no absolute "the best" solution for anything.

Comment: oh sorry dude it's my fault, yeah the first thing that i need to know is what class that have capability to do it. PHP have some function like opendir(), glob(), scandir() and RecursiveDirectoryIterator class.

Comment: to do *what*? Google for "how to profile php", then come when you have more particular question. "why this code is slow" is a really bad quality question.

Comment: sorry for my bad question @zerkms i want to know for my case, are you have some example about opendir(), glob(), scandir() and RecursiveDirectoryIterator class that have method with parameters?

Comment: Why do you need an example - you have already a snipped that apparently works already.

Comment: Should this be moved to Codereview?

Comment: yes of course @Andreas

Comment: @Khazefa How many files/directories are there in total in your start directory? The problem is most likely not PHP but the filesystem trying to read all files/directories. That said it might be wise to check only the directories which are relevant for your search. Please edit your question to include the directory structure, what you are trying to do/search and how you might be able to filter dictionary/files which aren't relevant for your search.

Answer (score 1):

use the below method to get your files with any extension in current directory and which takes

Total Execution Time: 0.00043816566467285 Mins

You can take a look at [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function which is far better than scandir.

```
if ( ! function_exists('glob_recursive'))
{
    // Does not support flag GLOB_BRACE

    function glob_recursive($pattern, $flags = 0)
    {
        $files = glob($pattern, $flags);

        foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir)
        {
            $files = array_merge($files, glob_recursive($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
        }

        return $files;
    }
}
$time_start = microtime(true);

//put your file extension to get all the files from current directory
$files = glob_recursive('*.png');

var_dump('<pre>', $files);
$time_end = microtime(true);

//dividing with 60 will give the execution time in minutes other wise seconds
$execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start) / 60;

//execution time of the script
echo '<br><b>Total Execution Time:</b> ' . $execution_time . ' Mins';
```

Comment: Big thanks mr @Mirza but still lack in processing time, Total Execution Time: 4.8777456680934 Mins, i'm still looking for class that capable doing that in less time..

Comment: how big the directories are?

Comment: this is the example of directory tree D:\DATA\PROGRAM 11\AREA 01\CAB 001\JS 0100 INSIGHT\2008\01 JANUARY\01

Comment: i think that structure is too deep for PHP classes works fastly