# Use GLOB to find distinct subfolders that contain a jpeg

Tags: php

I want to find all the folders that contain jpegs and store these folders in an array. I pass an empty array (folder_array) to the function, but because the function calls itself later on, the array gets wiped and all it returns is the last folder containing a jpeg. The code below works by listing details as the loop progress, but I want the results in the array

Also, my attempt to only find folders with jpegs is a little clumsy - any suggestions on how to improve it. Thanks in advance.

```
$folder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/photos";
chdir($folder);
$folder_array = array();
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext, $folder_array) {
    $globFiles = glob("$dir/*.$ext");
    $globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT);
    foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
        recursiveGlob($dir, $ext, $folder_array);
    }
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($globFiles as $file) {
        if ($count > 0) { // we've found a jpeg'
            if (!in_array($dir, $folder_array)) {
                array_push($folder_array,$dir);         
            }
        }
        $count++;
    }
    return $folder_array;
}   
$folder_array = recursiveGlob($folder, 'jpg', $folder_array);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I find you have way too many unclosed questions, IMHO. Would you be so kind as to marking the ones that were solved by others by accepting them? This is actually a "win-win" thing. It also shows that the question(s) was(were) solved by the system.

Comment: Look here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480434/5962802

Comment: I have a routine that will find all files of a particular type, but returns thousands of files. What I want is a list of the DISTINCT folders that contain that particular file type.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function r_glob( $dir, $ext ) {
    $result = [];
    if(trim($dir) === '') {
        $dir = '.';
    }
    $dir = pathinfo( $dir . '/./' )['dirname'] . '/';
    $files = glob($dir . '*.' . $ext );
    $result = $files;

    $subfolders = glob( $dir . '*', GLOB_ONLYDIR );
    foreach( $subfolders as $subfolder ) {
        $result = array_merge( $result, r_glob( $subfolder . '/', $ext ) );
    }

    return $result;
}

// all jpeg files in folder and subfolders
$jpg_files = r_glob('./', 'jpg'); 

// all folder/subfolders containing jpg images
$jpg_file_folders = array_unique( array_map( function($e) { return pathinfo($e)['dirname']; }, $jpg_files ) );

var_dump($jpg_files);
var_dump($jpg_file_folders);
```

If you want to have absolute paths use `realpath(...)` on each element of `$jpg_file_folders`

Comment: Pilan, $jpg_file_folders works beautifully. Thank you.